# Monitor number of instances of classes on heap

Tags: java, memory-leaks, heap-memory

The company I work for builds Java "enterprise software": large, complex, and often not well designed and maintained software. We've had regular problems with memory leaks which become visible within hours if not minutes. These memory leaks are clearly visible with normal monitoring of memory usage and taking heap dumps when it becomes critical.

Based on our monitoring it also looks like it is slowly leaking memory over a long period (weeks if not months). A single memory dump does not provide much insight in where memory is leaking and how it's developing over time.

So I'm looking for some kind of tool with can periodically produce/provide a report of the number instances for each class which currently reside in the heap. Much like `jmap -histo` can provide. But as this should run periodically on production instances it should have a low overhead, and not freeze the JVM.

2GiB of active heap with 29M instances of 27K classes are not uncommon numbers.

Comment: I suppose the usual "enterprise-grade" solution of restarting the application every Sunday at 2 am is off the table?

Comment: There is no way to monitor this information without some overhead.  The tool with the lowest overhead would be flight recorder, though this requires a license in production.

Comment: @Thilo I prefer to actually solve problems. And given the fact that it leaks quite slowly it rarely leaks long enough for it to become a problem as the servers receive regular maintenance, and thus a reboot every month or two isn't weird.

Answer (score 0):

Check out heapSpank from heapSpank.org -- I'm the author.
heapSpank executes jmap -histo at intervals you can configure.
It shows the percentage of time that byte counts are on the rise for the 15 classes most likely to be leaking.
This percentage is called the "leaky percentage" -- denoted as LKY%.
The class with with LKY% of 100% are the most likely leak suspects.

Here are the advantages of the approach:

- The overhead of capturing jmap -histo data is significantly lower than that of heapdumps.
- No need to restart JVM, as you do to hook up a profiler.
- If you are comfortable executing jmap -histo a few times in production, heapSpank only adds a small amount of overhead on top of that.
- open source and pure java solution.
- just download the small (2mb) executable jar file and pass in the pid of the leaky JVM.

Disadvantages:

- no support for permgen/metaspace leaks.
- does not support jmap's connection to remote JVMs.
- only works on HotSpot JDK -- does not work on IBM J9.
  [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41138610/programmatically-get-jmap-histo-data-from-ibm-j9) is my request for help in trying to support the J9.

Here are a few notes on keeping overhead low.

[This link](https://github.com/eostermueller/heapSpank/wiki/Configuration) provides details on configuration.
Increase this interval to further lower overhead:

```
org.heapspank.jmap.histo.interval.seconds=5
```

By default, to keep overhead low, heapSpank does not pass the -live parameter to jmap -histo.
But there is a tradeoff.  Not using the -live parameter provides less accurate results.

```
#If true, jmap -histo is passed the '-live' parameter, 
#which forces a full GC with every jmap -histo run.
#Using true will identify leak suspects more quickly & accurately, 
#but will incur extra GC overhead.  
org.heapspank.jmap.histo.live=false
```

Currently, heapSpank is a command-line program with a unix 'top' like display.  [The heapSpank roadmap](https://github.com/eostermueller/heapSpank/wiki/Roadmap) shows that we'd like to deploy this same technology with common/popular open-source monitoring tools and containers.